# How to increase date using php based on condition?

Tags: php, date

**Well, I have following code :**  It's return next all date base on given date until `do-while` loop end.

```
$paid = 2600;
$monthly = 700;

$x=0;
do {
    $monthly;   

    $date = date('2016'.'-'.'05'.'-d');
    $time = strtotime($date);
    $bill_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+$x month", $time));
    echo "$bill_month => $monthly <br/>";

    $paid -= $monthly;
    if ($paid < $monthly) {
        $monthly = $paid;
    }
$x++;
} while ($paid > 0);
```

**It's return following result :**

```
2016-05-12 => 700
2016-06-12 => 700
2016-07-12 => 700
2016-08-12 => 500
```

And I have another `array` which is bellow :

```
$date_array = array("2016-05-12", "2016-07-12");
```

**Now I want to show following date using above `do-while loop` :**

```
2016-06-12
2016-08-12
2016-09-12
2016-10-12
```

**I mean :**

You know above do while loop return all next date until end the loop. for example : next 4 months from given date.

But I want to show next 4 months which is not exist in `$date_array`. That's mean these 4 months :

```
2016-06-12
2016-08-12
2016-09-12
2016-10-12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if generated is not in `$date_array`, if it is get next month:

```
$found = false;
while (!$found) {
   $date = date('2016'.'-'.'05'.'-d');
   $time = strtotime($date);
   $bill_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+$x month", $time));
   $found = !in_array($bill_month,$date_array);
   ++$x;
}

echo "$bill_month => $monthly <br/>";
```

and remove `++$x` at and of while loop

cleaner if

```
$bill_month = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(($x++) . " month"),$time));
```

Full example:

```
<?php
/**
*/

$paid = 2600;
$monthly = 700;
$date_array = array("2016-05-12", "2016-07-12");
$x=0;
do {

    $found = false;
    while (!$found) {
        $date = date('2016'.'-'.'05'.'-d');
        $time = strtotime($date);
        $bill_month = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( ($x++)." month", $time));
        $found = !in_array($bill_month,$date_array);
    }

    echo "$bill_month => $monthly <br/>\n";

    $paid -= $monthly;
    if ($paid < $monthly) {
        $monthly = $paid;
    }
} while ($paid > 0);
```

Comment: let me check it @cske.

Comment: it's does not output the next 4 months according to my given example.

Comment: can you show me my desire all 4 months according to my given data ?

Comment: can I ask one more questions : now `in_array` check exact date. Can I check only year and month only. No day ?

Comment: free coding service? :) hints: simply skip day part from check and append back when echoing  `date("Y-m", strtotime( ($x++)." month", $time));` `$date_array = array("2016-05", "2016-07");`

Comment: ha ha ha :) Thanks anyway.